# Could not find method compile() for arguments [project ':react-native-sqlite']

Tags: sqlite, ubuntu, react-native

react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.42.0
npm :3.5.2

I install sqlite on react native using this tutorial:
https://github.com/remobile/react-native-sqlite
when I'm done I executed this command :
react-native run-android
I have this error :

```
Cannot parse yarn version: 0.22
Scanning 547 folders for symlinks in /home/sofiane/projet/sql/node_modules (6ms)
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/sofiane/projet/sql/android/build.gradle' line: 9

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'sql'.
> Could not find method compile() for arguments [project ':react-native-sqlite'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

build.gradle :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    compile project(':react-native-sqlite')
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In 2022 I ran into this issue with an old custom library, in the library's build.gradle replace `compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'` with `implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"`

Comment: @wizebin do I have to change that every time I install some new library?

Comment: If you're the library maintainer just change it in your library's build.gradle, if not you should submit a PR. If neither of those options is viable you can use the npm module "patch-package" to automatically patch the library.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should configure `<name-project>/android/app/build.gradle'` not `<name-project>/android/build.gradle'`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the structure of the gradle file was the problem, i accidetally duplicated the dependencias on allprojects session

from :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies { //=> duplicated
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:6.0.1"
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

to

```
buildscript {
    ext.objectboxVersion = '2.1.0'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:6.0.1"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Hope this helps someone.